# declaring New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application outside of Sub makes the VSTO COM addin to freeze during loading

Tags: vsto, excel-addins, comaddin

I have created an Excel COM add in which opens a windows form from a ribbon button. I want to populate the combobox using data from an external excel spreadsheet as well as populate the textboxes based on the selected name.

[The part of the form where this applies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bn1z.png)

when placing the block of code:

```
Dim ExcelApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ' this is causing the issue
Dim ClientListBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SoftwareDev\Desktop\ASSETS\MasterFile.xlsx")
Dim ClientListSheet = ClientListBook.Sheets(1)
```

below the `Public Class Form1` as seen below:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Dim ExcelApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ' this is causing the issue
        Dim ClientListBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SoftwareDev\Desktop\ASSETS\MasterFile.xlsx")
        Dim ClientListSheet = ClientListBook.Sheets(1)

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbClientName.SelectedIndexChanged

            End Sub
```

it causes the Add in to freeze

But when Placing the same block of code into the Sub Form1_Load and Sub  ComboBox1 as seen below, the add in works although it is very slow and i suspect it is an incorrect implementation.

THIS IS THE WORKING FULL CODE FOR THE FORM:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbClientName.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim ExcelApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ' this is causing the issue
        Dim ClientListBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SoftwareDev\Desktop\ASSETS\MasterFile.xlsx")
        Dim ClientListSheet = ClientListBook.Sheets(1)

        Dim iStartedRow As Integer
        Dim iTotalRows As Integer

        ' count the number of rows in the worksheet
        iTotalRows = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        ' populates the textboxes using clientList data

        For iStartedRow = 2 To iTotalRows
            If Me.cmbClientName.Text = ClientListSheet.Cells(iStartedRow, 1).text Then
                Me.txtSal.Text = ClientListSheet.Cells(iStartedRow, 4).text
                Me.txtInvMan.Text = ClientListSheet.Cells(iStartedRow, 5).text
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ExcelApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ' this is causing the issue
        Dim ClientListBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SoftwareDev\Desktop\ASSETS\MasterFile.xlsx")
        Dim ClientListSheet = ClientListBook.Sheets(1)

        Dim StartedRow As Integer
        Dim TotalRows As Integer

        ' clear any existing data 
        Me.cmbClientName.Items.Clear()

        ' count the number of rows in the worksheet
        TotalRows = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        ' create a loop to add data into combobox
        For StartedRow = 2 To TotalRows
            Me.cmbClientName.Items.Add(ClientListSheet.Cells(StartedRow, 1).Text)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Please would you let me know how i can correctly implement this and if it would be better and faster to use Microsoft Access database instead. I am new to VSTO COM add ins and VB.Net, this is my first project so i understand that my implementation may be suboptimal and will appreciate all feedback.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare and initialize these variables on the class level, they are created when the constructor runs.

There is absolutely no reason to initialize them immediately - you can declare them on the class level, but create them only when needed

Moreover, if your code is running in a VSTO addin, there is absolutely no reason to create an instance of the `Excel.Application` object -  it is already available to you.

Hardcoding the file path is obviously also a problem...

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ExcelAppe
    Dim ClientListBook
    Dim ClientListSheet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ExcelApp = Globals.ThisAddin.Application
        ClientListBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SoftwareDev\Desktop\ASSETS\MasterFile.xlsx")
        ClientListSheet = ClientListBook.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and the solution you provided works perfectly the only thing is when i click on one of the entries it redirects to the excel sheet where the information is pulled from, ideally i would want to keep the form at the front always, ill have a look into that. Also with regards to the file path, since the program will run on different machines i created a textbox where the user can define the file path from their PC. Thank you for your help

Comment: I added "Me.TopMost = True" under the ClientListSheet= ClientListBook.Sheets(1) that seemed to do the trick for that